How to make dir command never truncate filenames, folder names, or paths by using ellipses? (Windows 11)
In the command processor (Windows 11), how does one prevent the output from commands such as dir from having long pathnames or filenames truncated with ellipses (..)?
I'm particularly interested in answers that pertain to when stdout is redirected to a file.
For example, if you run the command dir c:\windows\winsxs /a/s > test.txt, you will notice that long names within the output will have parts of their names replaced with  double-dot ellipses (..).
How can this be changed so that all characters are always displayed?

You can try adding /b to only list the files with full path rather than its summary.

@LPChip Thanks.  I do need all the other details provided by the dir command as well.

In that case, you will probably get a better result going the powershell route. something like dir  "c:\windows\winsxs" -recurse | out-file c:\test.txt

@LPChip, the PowerShell DIR command has same limitation, e.g. amd64_microsoft-windows-a...appxmain.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_en-us_336daaaf7b798f62, as does DIR /b ... and I've not found an alternative that does work.

@DrMoishePippik I think LPChip figured it out (answer below).  I can't believe it, but I think that's the correct answer.  Do you concur?

I did a bit of testing, and you're never gonna believe the answer.
All the tests etc you did are okay.
The directores actually contain the .. themselves.
I have a feeling a script made them, that had to truncate the folders in order to limit to a 240 character limit.
I can perform a dir in powershell or cmd, find a folder that has these .., then go to Windows Explorer, navigate to that folder, find the folder with .. in it, get its properties, and find the .. in there too.
So yes, these folders are actually named like this, its not a weird thing dir does, they literally are called like that.
It sounds weird, but you can test this yourself. Just create a new folder somewhere, for example in C:\Temp, and call it Test..ing. You'll find that it is perfectly allowed to have multiple dots in a row in the name.

Oh my goodness. Are you serious? I spent hours trying everything in cmd & PowerShell to get rid of the ellipses in my output.  I had a hunch something was amiss because the ellipses are only 2 dots, and generally ellipses are 3 dots.  But I persisted.  I think I literally tried over 20 different coding techniques.  I used PowerShell directly.  I used PowerShell to call .NET functions.  I used PowerShell to call C# functions.  I tried so many techniques.  I just figured I was doing something wrong.  I'm actually relieved by your answer, but I'm still shaking my head in disbelief.

Great testing! And of course . and .. are directories, just to obfuscate the issue further. An MS invented Dot.Net.

Yes, I'm very serious. :) I don't think you are looking for any answer anymore, so feel free to mark this question as solved so others know you no longer need help. :)
